# Reflection VS static stuff

Tags: java, reflection, static

Recently I've been restructuring a Java code of mines trying to eliminate, wherever possible, `static` stuff (variables and methods) and replace it with better coding practices.

I also started studying reflection and noticed that it allows me to do some things<sup>1</sup> that, at first, I could only achieve (or, at least, that's how I see it) with `static` calls or references.

However, while I've been reading that the use of `static` is not much recommended, it doesn't seem to be the same with reflection.

So, I'm asking: instead of making a method `static` and calling it like `ClassName.methodName()`, is it a legitimate use of reflection making it an instance method and invoking it by `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()`?

---

<sup>1</sup> like dynamically accessing a class' content

---

Here's a code sample:

Hypothetic situation that works (but I don't want to make the method `static`):

```
import static java.lang.System.out;


public class Foo
{
    private static boolean light;


    public Foo()
    {
        turnOn();
    }

    public static void turnOn()
    {
        light = true;
    }

    public static void turnOff()
    {
        light = false;
    }

    public static boolean isGreenLight()
    {
        return light;
    }
}

public class Boo
{
    public Boo()
    {
        if (Foo.isGreenLight())        // I need to access Foo.isGreenLight() from here, but cur-
        {                              // rently that method is not static (it should be to do so)
            out.println("Ok!");
        }
    }
}

public final class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Boo boo = new Boo();
    }
}
```

Hypothetic situation that also should work (how it'd be using reflection):

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class Foo
{
    private boolean light;


    public Foo()
    {
        turnOn();
    }

    public void turnOn()
    {
        this.light = true;
    }

    public void turnOff()
    {
        this.light = false;
    }

    public boolean isGreenLight()
    {
        return this.light;
    }
}

public class Boo
{
    public Boo()
    {
        if ((boolean) Class.forName("Foo").getMethod("isGreenLight", null).invoke(new Foo(), null))
        {
            out.println("Ok!");
        }
    }
}

public final class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Boo boo = new Boo();
    }
}
```

*Expected output (untested):*

> Ok!

Comment: It is not a question of how to make the call (direct vs reflection), but about changing the method *itself* to be non-static. If you simply change the direct call to be a reflection call, but leave the method as a static method, then you've just made you code *worse!!*

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "retrieve a value from that method"? Get the value it returns? Maybe you should give some code samples.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I'm talking about the eventuality of changing the method to be non-static, and accessing it by Reflection

Comment: @C.Champagne Yes, I'm referring to its return value

Comment: But *why* are you trying to access it by reflection? What is it that reflection solves in the conversion of code from static methods to non-static methods? Or are you implementing your own injection framework?

Comment: My advice would be not to touch reflection except for learning purposes and after that only when you need it. It's rarely necessary to use it, and if you're thinking "I'll solve this with reflection" it most likely means "I've written bad code".

Comment: _" if you're thinking 'I'll solve this with reflection' it most likely means 'I've written bad code'"_ -- indeed, see my answer

Comment: @Andreas In this case it would solve the problem I am facing right now, that is I can't call `isGreenLight()` from `Boo` class cause it is not `static` (and it mustn't be). But, like said, I don't know if **this** use of reflection as an easy work-around is legit

Comment: @Kayaman I think this is one case in which asking oneself if reflection could be a solution is acceptable

Comment: Generally reflection is much harder to reason about  ("magic happens from far away") than something which is declared static.  I think you do yourself and other maintainers of your code a disservice if you replace static things by reflective things; the code just gets a lot harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: Your hypothetical situation still doesn't help; justify your design decision and determine if it's correct usage of said design paradigm or not. Rewrite your code test-first and compare & contrast.

Comment: @LorenzoMaffii If you can't call `Boo.isGreenLight()` because the method is not static, how does reflection help you? You'll need an instance of `Boo` to call the method, whether you call the method normally or using reflection, so I'm still not clear on what problem it is that you think reflection is solving. Your hypothetical solution is very long `(boolean) Class.forName("Foo").getMethod("isGreenLight", null).invoke(new Foo(), null)`, and is doing the same as this `new Foo().isGreenLight()`, without using reflection and without the need for a cast. Reflection is not the answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Using reflection is a code smell, especially if the intent behind what you're writing does not warrant it.

It is difficult to say much more without seeing code as it's all just guesswork.

I would:

- enumerate the reasons behind why you had those `static` members in the first place
- determine if the `static` modifier was in fact the right decision in the first place: i.e. should these be instance or class members? How might they be used by "clients" of the classes in question? What paradigm am I using? Functional or Object Oriented code. Does it satisfy DRY, SOLID and KISS programming practices?
- consider if I'm over-engineering in the first place

More importantly:

- I would design my code through tests **first**, which drives the design of your API through the eye of the user, with the added benefit that you have test coverage before you've even implemented. Often times when writing code this way I eliminate such questions because the solution is more obvious when thought from the perspective of a user rather than a designer. It becomes a question of pragmatism rather than satisfying architectural design goals and philosophies.

Comment: I am not sure you are aver engineering the first point. I feel that `static` is overused by the OP but I admit it is hard to tell without example

Comment: How can justifying a design decision be over-engineering?

Comment: Sorry if my comment was ambiguous. I meant I was almost sure that this is not over-engineering. I just made a reference to  your third point. I totally agree with your answer indeed.

Comment: Ahh fair enough! Sorry, I assumed the worst when I misread! xD

Comment: @atc Actually those members aren't `static`. Making them `static` would probably ease things for me, but I'd prefer to avoid this, so I was thinking of other ways to achieve the same result without using it. And I thought of reflection